# How to get different value from same column from same table - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which has four column

```
--------------------------------------
| ID | DESCRIPTION | PAY | TIMESTAMP |
--------------------------------------
| 1  | ABA123      | 100 | 02-10-2019|
--------------------------------------
| 2  | ABA123      | 200 | 02-06-2019|
--------------------------------------
| 3  | ABA123      | 300 | 01-11-2019|
```

In my requirement I need to fetch 1 day old pay, 5 days old pay and 1 month old pay and suppose today is March 11, 2019. I can run three queries to fetch the data as follows.

```
select * from salary where timestamp <= sysdate -1 ; // this will return row with one day old salary
select * from salary where timestamp 
<= sysdate -1 and timestamp >= sysdate -4  // this one return all records between 1 to 4 days old and I can have similar query for one month old data
```

Is there any way I can run one query which will display the result in following format

```
| DESCRIPTION | 1DAYPAY | 4DAYPAY | 1MONTHPAY |
----------------------------------------------------
| ABA123      | 100     | 200     | 300       |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `sum()` function then `add_months` for your `1 month` old data.

```
select description
    , sum(case when timestamp between sysdate and sysdate - 1 then Pay else 0 end)
    , sum(case when timestamp between sysdate and sysdate - 4 then Pay else 0 end)
    , sum(case when timestamp between sysdate and add_months(sysdate,-1) then Pay else 0 end)
from salary
group by description
```

Comment: What should I do If I am adding or finding max value. What if I have only records for Pay for that day ?

Comment: @ashish, i'm using sum() because in case we have multiple pay, but you can replace it to max() if you want the maximum

Comment: I would suggest using `WHERE` clause like `timestamp between sysdate and add_months(sysdate,-1) ` to avoid processing unnecessary records.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation.  I'm not sure what the exact logic is for the three periods you want:

```
select description,
       max(case when timestamp >= sysdate - 1 then salary end),
       max(case when timestamp >= sysdate - 4 and timestamp < sysdate - 1 then salary end),      
       max(case when ? then salary end)  -- whatever the logic is for one month  
from salary
group by description;
```

You may also want `sum()` rather than `max()`.

Comment: What should I do If I am adding or finding max value. What if I have only records for Pay for that day ?

Comment: @ashish . . . You can just use `max()`.